# Find rows having same values in multiple columns(Not All Columns) in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my Dataframe:

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
A   B   C   10  BAM
A   A   A   12  BAM
B   B   B   10  BAM
A   B   B   60  BAM
```

I want those rows having `same values`  in `columns(X1, X2,X3)`. Here we can see `2nd` and `3rd` rows  are having same values for above 3 columns.
 My desired output is:

```
 X1 X2  X3  X4  X5
A   A   A   12  BAM
B   B   B   10  BAM
```

I tried like below:

```
yourdf1=df[df.nunique(0)==0]
print(yourdf1)
```

But here i am getting an error. Could anyone please help me.

Comment: No it is not the duplicate.. There we are getting rows having same values across all the columns. But here i want only for particular few columns.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Selecting columns is a trivial step and not worth disputing closure over.

Answer (score 11):

Select columns in list for test number of unique values per rows by `axis=1` in [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) and test `1` for filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
yourdf1 = df[df[['X1','X2','X3']].nunique(axis=1) == 1]
print(yourdf1)
  X1 X2 X3  X4   X5
1  A  A  A  12  BAM
2  B  B  B  10  BAM
```

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with filtered `DataFrame`, compare by first column and get all Trues per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df1 = df[['X1','X2','X3']]
yourdf1 = df[df1.eq(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)]
print(yourdf1)

  X1 X2 X3  X4   X5
1  A  A  A  12  BAM
2  B  B  B  10  BAM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yourdf = df[~df.duplicated(subset=['X1','X2','X3'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see attached

```
df[df[['X1','X2','X3']].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each row and compare columns with each other, and attach the rows which are the same to a new dataframe.
The code would look something like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for row in df.rows:
    if (row['X1'] == row['X2']  and row['X2'] == row['X3']):
       df2.append(row)
display(df2)
```